# Blazor - how to use brotli compression

Tags: web-config, compression, blazor, brotli

Blazor WASM supports gzip/brotli compression. [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1) shows example [web.config](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/master/aspnetcore/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly/_samples/web.config)
however this web.config is not using hosted model.

If I merge example web.config with root web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\app.Server.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Javascript files, css, images becomes unreachable. I also tried put example web.config into wwwroot/_framework folder, however no change at all.

Comment: Did you even find a solution to this?

Comment: @jimlayhey I found hosted solution e.g. IIS - ASP.NET Core dont require web.config. IIS do it. However I have old Windows Server which dont implement brotli yet. gzip works